# Puppet installation error

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install Puppet master(3.8) open source and i am following this document 
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/install_el.html

I am getting below error :

yum install puppetserver
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
**file:///opt/puppetlabs/server/data/packages/public/2017.2.1/el-6-x86_64-1.10.1/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///opt/puppetlabs/server/data/packages/public/2017.2.1/el-6-x86_64-1.10.1/repodata/repomd.xml**
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: puppet_enterprise. Please verify its path and try again

Any idea what is wrong i am doing.

Comment: Use the documentation for the version you are installing: https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/install_basic.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard the link you have provided is for PE.
I am looking Puppet Community version(Open source)

Comment: The error message you provided is for PE 2017.2.1.

Comment: It was Yum issue and i was able to fix that ,It has nothing to do with Puppet.

Thank you @MattSchuchard.